# UTF8 encoding of strings on mac terminals

Tags: macos, shell

I'm new to mac, and when I want to use base64 encoding on mac's terminal, I can do this:

```
echo -n "some simple words" | base64
```

When I want to use UTF8 encoding for a string, how should I do it?

Comment: macOS tends to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for strings, meaning most strings *already are* in UTF-8. If you have a string in some other encoding, and want to convert it to UTF-8, you'd need to mention what that other encoding is.

Answer (score 1):

To encode this to UTF-8, the command is:

```
echo -n "some simple words"
```

That is UTF-8 encoding.

If you want the hex values of the encoding, dump it into xxd:

```
echo -n "some simple words" | xxd
```